# Proving a function to be surjective

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

f : **N** → **N**  and g : **N** → **N**, and define h: **N** → **N** by the
rule h = g ◦ f

if f and g are both surjective, then so is h.

So what I have so far is that the codomains are all the same, **N**, and so since N -> N are the same for both f and g, it must be surjective because it will have all the same natural numbers. so for any natural number in F, there is the same in g, so g(f(x)) must be onto g(f(y))?

how else do i prove that h is surjective

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $z \in \bf N$, since $g$ is surjective there is $y \in \bf N$ such that $g(y) = z$, and since $f$ is surjective there is $x \in \bf N$ such that $f(x) = y$.  Thus $(g \circ f)(x) = z$.

Comment: i'm trying to now prove that if H is surhective, then so is f. would this be  a correct proof if i say: (g o f)(x) = (g o f)(y) is surjective. if x ∈ **N**, any x where there exists a y ∈ N, such that h(y) = x. and i can set z = f(y)∈**N**. Then, g(z)=g(f(y))=x. therefore g is surjective. @Robert Israel, does this look right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to prove that for every $b\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists $a\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $h(a)=b$, that is $g(f(a))=b$.

Let $b\in\mathbb{N}$. Since $g$ is surjective we know that that there exists $c$ such that $g(c)=b$. Can you finish the proof?

Answer (score 0):

Consider any $c\in \mathbb{N}.$ Since $g$ is surjective there exists $b\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $g(b)=c.$ Since $f$ is surjective there exists $a\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f(a)=b.$ Now, note that

$$h(a)=g(f(a))=g(b)=c.$$ This shows that $h$ is surjective.

Answer (score 0):

Assume n is not g(f(x)) for all x. But since f is surjective, this is just to say n is not g(y) for all y. But then g is not surjective, a contradiction.